# Javascript createElement function

Tags: javascript, function

I have some code which is replicated throughout the main.js file

Javascript duplicates examples:

```
Example 1
for (i = userVote; i < 5; i++) {
var newVotesInput = document.createElement("input");
newVotesInput.id = "vote" + i;
newVotesInput.classList.add("vote", "displayn");
newVotesInput.type = "radio";
newVotesInput.name = "vote";
newVotesInput.value = i;
someElement.appendChild(newVotesInput);
}

Example 2
for (i = 1; i <= userVote; i++) {
var newVotesLabel = document.createElement("label");
newVotesLabel.id = "voteLabel" + i;
newVotesLabel.classList.add("voteHover");
newVotesLabel.htmlFor = "vote" + i;
someElement.appendChild(newVotesLabel);
}

Example 3
var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.classList.add("babeImg", "boxsb", "leftIn");
newImg.id = "imgSrc";
newImg.src = jsonData.imgSrc;
someElement.appendChild(newImg);

Example 4
var newShuffle = document.createElement("img");
newShuffle.classList.add("shuffleImg");
newShuffle.id = "shuffleImg";
newShuffle.src = "assets/img/refresh.png";
someElement.appendChild(newShuffle);

Example 5
newImg.classList.add("babeImg", "boxsb", "leftIn");
newImg.id = "imgSrc";
newImg.src = jsonData.imgSrc;
imgInner.appendChild(newImg);
```

As you can see the examples do the same which is creating an element but there are several parameters which differs from example to example.
How do i make a function that i can use for all of them?
right now i only know how to build one for exactly one specific example like so ->

```
function createElement(element, id, cls, src){
var newElement = document.createElement(element);
element.id = id;
element.classList.add(cls);
element.src = src;
someElement.appendChild(element);
}
```

This is bascially Example 4.. but how do i make this more efficient and useable on all of the examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following function:

```
function createElement(type, attributes) {
  var element = document.createElement(type);
  for (var key in attributes) {
    if (key == "class") {
        element.classList.add.apply(element.classList, attributes[key]); // add all classes at once
    } else {
      element[key] = attributes[key];
    }
  }
  someElement.appendChild(element);
}
```

The function takes a type (`input`, `img`, etc) and a list of attributes (i.e. an object/dictionary). We loop through the attributes and add them to the new element. The only special case is with classes, with use a different syntax (and we can have multiple classes). Here is how you can use it:

```
var input = createElement("input", {
  "id": "myId",
  "class": ["one-class", "another-class"],
  "name": "someName"
});
```

Note that the `class` has an array as a value.

The result will be:

```
<input id="myId" class="one-class another-class" name="someName">
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dro46uda/1/).

---

**EDIT**

To better understand: in JS, objects are like dictionaries, i.e. a bunch of key-value pairs (and `prototypes`, but this is not important for this discussion).

If you have an object with an `id` attribute, you can access it using one of the following syntax:

```
myObject.id   // object style
myObject["id"] // dictionary style
```

The second syntax is very useful, since you can use variables to access object attributes:

```
var attr = "id";
myObject[attr];
```

Now, we can also iterate over an object, as we do with arrays. The only difference is that with arrays, the `for in` syntax returns the index, while with objects it returns the `key` or property name.

```
var myObject = { "id": 1, "name": "a name" }; // a basic object

for(var key in myObject) console.log(key, myObject[key]);
// will print 
// id 1
// name a name
```

If you understand these two mecanics, the code I gave you will get much clearer.

Comment: This looks like nothing i have done before, i will take a good look at what you have done here and try to solve it.

Comment: Please don't use `for-in` on an Array. It causes problems. Either way, you really don't need a loop to add the classes from the Array. `element.classList.add(...cls);` Or to support older browsers without using a transpiler: `element.classList.add.apply(element.classList, cls)`

Comment: I tried to make it as simple as I could (for loops are often presented in the first JS lessons), but I completely agree with your comment and updated my answer.

Comment: I am really impressed by the way this works
Thanks alot this will become very handy for me in the future :)

Bookmarked and upvoted :)